# Does one php script being used by multiple users share same memory limit

Tags: php, memory-management

I have a php script which uses lot of memory. If I set memory limit for this script to 32 megabytes, does this 32 megabytes of memory will be used/shared by all users accessing the script OR each user will have his own chunk of 32 megabytes?

Comment: Each script execution is independent of every other. If you've got 30 copies of the script running and each is using up 30 megs of ram, then you've got 900 megs of ram in use on the server. The limit is per-script-invocation, not per-all-users-of-the-script.

Comment: Each user or specifically *request*, will use 32 megabytes.

Comment: Where did you set the limit?

Comment: @hek2mgl in top of my script via ini_set

Comment: is 32 mb "a lot" any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32MB limit will be imposed on a per-**request** basis, users won't be competing for memory (with regards to this memory limit).

Comment: "users won't be competing for memory" they will be if they request the script  simultaneously.